# Find max in array with recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I want to find the max number in array by recursion,
What wrong with this code.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int find_max(int *a,int n){
    int m_max;
    if(n==1){
        return a[0];
    }
    m_max=find_max(a,n-1);
    if(a[n-1]>m_max)
        m_max=a[n-1];
}
```

Comment: There isn't a return when n != 1

Answer (score 3):

1. As @moffeltje comments, "There isn't a return when n != 1"

   ```
     if(a[n-1]>m_max) 
       m_max=a[n-1];
     return m_max;  // add
   }
   ```
2. This linear approach gives recursion a bad name.  If there are `n` numbers, the maximum recursive depth is `n`.  Much better to divide in 2 for a max depth of `log2(n)`

   ```
   int find_max(const int *a, int n) {
     if (n <= 1) {
       return a[0];
     }
     int left = find_max(a, n/2);
     int right = find_max(&a[n/2], n - n/2);
     return left > right ? left : right;
   }
   ```

--- Minor stuff follows

3. Cope with corner cases where `n < 1` or `a == NULL`.

   ```
   int find_max(const int *a, int n) {
     if (n <= 1 || a == NULL) {
       if (n <= 0 || a == NULL) return INT_MIN;  // or throw error
       return a[0];
     }
     ...
   ```
4. Changing `int find_max(int *a, int n)` --> `int find_max(const int *a, int n)` allows constant arrays to be passed also.
5. Array sizes are best typed as `size_t` rather than `int`.

   ```
   int find_max(const int *a, size_t n) {
     ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int find_max(int *a,int n){
    int m_max;
    if(n==1){
        return a[0];
    }
    m_max=find_max(a,n-1);
    if(a[n-1]>m_max)
        m_max=a[n-1];
    return m_max;
}
```

you have not returned anything when n!=1.
Look when designing these things you should always check the -

> **The base case.** Here in this case it is achieved when n=1.(one element left and it is the largest one)
>
> **The recursive case.** Here you will use the computed values to smaller cases and now you will build the solution thinking that the previous cases are calcualted already.
>
> **Combine** Combine the calculate results. The last if condition that you have provided. But you forgot to put a return that is not giving the result to one stage to others. That's where there is this problem.

Comment: there is another way to do this?

Comment: @user3234880.: Using recursion you can do it this way. But simply using a variable you can also do this..int max=a[0]; for(i=1;i<n;i++) if(a[i]>max) max=a[i];

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could simplify the function.

```
int max_array_val( int* a_Array, int a_Size )
{
    int max = a_Array[ 0 ];

    for( int i = 1;  i < a_Size;  i++ )
        if( a_Array[ i ] > max )
            max  = a_Array[ i ];

    return max;
}

int main()
{
    int int_array[ 6 ] = { 3, 2, 6, 5, 5, 2 };

    printf( "Maximum number is: %i\n\n", max_array_val( int_array, sizeof( int_array ) / sizeof( int ) ) );
    system( "pause" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It has to be with a recursion, if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
int getMax(int const * arr, int size) {
    if (size == 1)
        return *arr;

    int ans = getMax(arr + 1, size - 1);
    return *arr > ans ? *arr : ans;
}
```